# Use of integrals for multiple variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

If we have more than one variable in an integral,why don't we always use more than one integral sign? For example if we deal with moment of inertia of a sphere,we take a volume element $dV$,then measure it's distance $r$ from $z$ axis and thereby determine the moment of inertia of that element as $\rho dVr^2$. For finding the total moment of inertia we then simply add all those of individual elements,which becomes $\int \rho r^2 dV$. But later on,we split this one integral into $3$ integrals for $r,\theta,\phi$ and hence we rewrite the integral as $\int \int \int \rho r^2 r^2 \sin \theta dr d\theta d\phi$. As we can see we are using $3$ integrals for $3$ different variables. Then why don't we do the same for line integrals? In line integrals,there is $x,y$ term present in a single integral sign. Shouldn't we use $2$ integrals in that scenario for those $2$ variables. This has been bugging me for a long time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'line integral' at the end?

Comment: @Surge the one in vector calculus,where both $dx$ and $dy$ terms are present in a single integral sign.

Comment: Be precise, it's hard to know what you are referring to. In general, the number of integral signs is the same as the number of $d$'s. In any case, the technical explanation involves the measures over which you are integrating.

Comment: @Surge,say for example when we have a force $F=f(x,y) i+ g(x,y) j$,we determine the work by $F.dr$ which is a vector product with $dr=dx i+ dy j$. So the total work becomes $\int f(x,y)dx +g(x,y)dy$. Now what we do is we parameterize the curve. But why can't we replace the single integral sign here with a double integral?

Comment: In this case, it's an integral along a curve. You're not integrating over a surface. Also, notice how there's one integral sign and one $d$.